Can I create a react library with multiple entry points and typescript?
So I've been trying to create a vite/react library with multiple entry points. My idea is to have an entry point for utils, ui and hooks. I have tried to configure vite like this:
build: {
    rollupOptions: {
        input: [
             resolve(__dirname, "./src/ui/"),
             resolve(__dirname, "./src/hooks/"),
             resolve(__dirname, "./src/utils/")
        ]
    }
}

And then in my package.json:
"exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/index.js",
      "require": "./dist/index.umd.cjs"
    },
    "./hooks": {
      "import": "./dist/hooks.js",
      "require": "./dist/hooks.umd.cjs"
    },
    "./ui": {
      "import": "./dist/ui.js",
      "require": "./dist/ui.umd.cjs"
    },
    "./utils": {
      "import": "./dist/utils.js",
      "require": "./dist/utils.umd.cjs"
    }
  }

I realise this is probably more a typescript issue then an export, as I followed javascript tutorials. The vite project generated 3 files: tsconfig.json, tsconfig.node.json and tsconfig.app.json. What should I do in order to be able to import externally?
My idea is to have imports like:
import { Button } from "@my-lib/ui"
import { toQueryParams } from "@my-lib/utils"
import { useEventListener } from "@my-lib/hooks"

How excacly can i achieve this?
